# Within Django, how do I add a new value to request.POST data before saving?

Tags: python, django, request, immutability

I'm trying to allow the user to either manually enter a text field if they have the license info, or let it auto generate (based on form info) if its original content.

I'm stuck because from my tests (using print command) the form is correctly updating with the information given in the form if LicenseTag field is left blank. The issue is that the updated information is not being saved in the database. After research this seems to be an issue of immutability, which is why I added `request.POST.copy()` and tested the commented out section defining `mutability=True`.

Here's my views.py

```
def STLupload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        data = request.POST.copy()

        if form.is_valid():
            #Dis gona need alot of work
            firstname = request.user.first_name
            lastname = request.user.last_name
            displayname = request.user.display_name
            email = request.user.email


            if (firstname or lastname == "None"):
                if displayname == "None":
                    liscname = email
                else:
                    liscname = '%s %s' % (firstname, lastname)
            else:
                liscname = displayname


            filetitle = request.POST.get(
                'Title'
            , '')


            lisc = '%s %s' % (filetitle, liscname)

            if data['LicenseTag'] == "":

                '''
                mutable = request.POST._mutable
                request.POST._mutable = True
                request.POST['LicenseTag'] =  lisc
                request.POST._mutable = mutable
                '''

                data['LicenseTag'] = lisc
                print (request.POST.get(
                'LicenseTag'
                , ''))
                print ("blank")
            else:

            print (form)


            #Save current username
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user = request.user

            comment.save()

            #Flash success message
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "File uploaded successful")    

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('STLup'))
    else:
        form = NewUpload()  # A empty, unbound form
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to save the generated information into my database?

**Edit #1**

Models.py

```
  from django.db import models

  import os
  #import django.db.models.deletion
  from django.db import models
  from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
  from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
  from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
  from django.utils import timezone
  from django.conf import settings

  from django.contrib.auth.models import User


  # Create your models here.

  def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
      # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
          return os.path.join('uploads', str(instance.Title), filename)


  def validate_file_extension(value):
    ext = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1]
    valid_extensions = ['.stl','.STL']
    if not ext in valid_extensions:
      raise ValidationError(u'Please upload a .stl file type only')

  def validate_img_extension(value):
    ext = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1]
    valid_extensions = ['.jpg','.png','.JPG']
    if not ext in valid_extensions:
      raise ValidationError(u'Please upload a .jpg or .png only')

  class UploadedFiles(models.Model):

      user = models.ForeignKey(
      settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True)

      STL = models.FileField(_('STL Upload'), 
      upload_to=user_directory_path, validators=[validate_file_extension])
      Photo = models.ImageField(_('Photo'),
      upload_to=user_directory_path, validators=[validate_img_extension])

      Title = models.CharField(_('Title of object'),
       max_length=40, blank=False, null=True, unique=False)
      Category = models.CharField(_('Category'),
       max_length=40, blank=False, null=True, unique=False)
      SubCategory = models.CharField(_('SubCategory'),
       max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, unique=False)
      SubSubCategory = models.CharField(_('*SubSubCategory (optional)'),
       max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, unique=False)

      FileType = models.BooleanField(_('Local?'),
      default=0, unique=False)

      Description = models.TextField(_('File Description'),
       max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, unique=False)
      LicenseTag = models.CharField(_('*License (optional, leave blank for original content)'),
       max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, unique=False)


      Xdim_mm = models.IntegerField(_('X dimension (mm)'),
      default=0)
      Ydim_mm = models.IntegerField(_('Y dimension (mm)'),
      default=0)
      Zdim_mm = models.IntegerField(_('Z dimension (mm)'),
      default=0)

      pub_date = models.DateTimeField(_('date_joined'), default=timezone.now)
```

Here is my forms.py.

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator

from .models import UploadedFiles


class NewUpload(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = UploadedFiles
        fields = ('Title', 'STL','Photo','Description', 'Category', 'SubCategory', 'SubSubCategory', 'LicenseTag')
```

Comment: what is your model? what is your form? Why are you trying to modify POST? there is almost never a need for that

Comment: I've added my models and forms. All I want to do is create a database entry based on the user input form data. If there is another way to do this other then how I suggested I'm open to any other ideas .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it the best way is to override the save method in your model.

```
class UploadedFiles(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.LicenseTag:
            if self.user:
                liscname = self.user.get_full_name() or self.user.email
                self.LicenseTag = "{0} {1}".format(liscname, self.Title)

        super(UploadFiles,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Then the same thing works in your admin without having to do a lot of hard work. I have taken the liberty to optimize how the license tag is derived.

Now your view becomes a whole lot simpler.

```
def STLupload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            lisc = '%s %s' % (filetitle, liscname)

            #Save current username
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user = request.user

            comment.save()

            #Flash success message
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "File uploaded successful")    

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('STLup'))
    else:
        form = NewUpload()  # A empty, unbound form
```

Comment: This is 96% correct, but I would like for my liscname to try full_name, display_name, then email in that order.  How would I have it check those 3 instead of just 2 within the liscname variable? Works perfect for saving to the db though!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best is to save(commit=False) and then add required fields

```
form = MyForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.licence = 'your license code'
    obj.save()
```